# why am I seeing undefined in my console instead of the value of the input

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to log the value of my input to the console but anytime I click on the submit button it log undefined please why is this happening.
here is my code below

```
<!--html-->
<body>
  <form action="" id="form">
     <input type="text" name="" id="input" />
     <input type="submit" name="" id="submit" />
  </form>
</body>

 <!--script-->
 <script>
     const form = document.querySelector('#form');
     const input = document.querySelector('#input');
     const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

     function adds(e) {
       console.log(e.target.value);

        e.preventDefault();
     }
     form.addEventListener('submit', adds);   
 </script>
```

Comment: `console.log(e.target);` What is it? That would answer why it is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.target` is an `HTMLFormElement`. It has no `value` property.

If you want to get the value of the input, either reference it via `input` or `form.firstChild`.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

function adds(e) {
  console.log(form.firstChild.value);

  e.preventDefault();
}
form.addEventListener('submit', adds);
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="" id="input" />
    <input type="submit" name="" id="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks man I understand javascript is my first programming language that is why I easily get confused